# Refresh hive tables in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop2, impala

I have few tables in Hive, every day new csv file will be adding to the hive table location. When a new data is available i need to refresh the tables so that i can see new data in the tables.

steps we follow to load the data:

- first create a table with csv serde properties
- create another table with parquet table to do in production
- insert the data from first table to second table.

Initial:

1,a

2,b

3,c

New file:

4,d

I searched in google and found this can be done via:

1) incremental table, loading the new file in to incremental table and do insert statement. In my case we have more than 100 tables and so not want to create these many incremental tables

2) Using refresh command via Impala shell.
Our initial tables are stored as csv serde format. so when i do refresh on the initial tables i get an error impala does't support  serde propertied.

Can you please provide a solution in my case.

Comment: and why not simply put new file in table location? (CSV-based)

Comment: I have put the new file in the table location, But when i query from hive table new data in not popping up. - @leftjoin

Comment: When i add the file in the location, date is available in the first table (in csv serde properties) But it did not come in to parquet i.e. production table

Comment: insert the data from first table to second table - looks good if you need to load data into table with different file type (CSV and parquet). Steps you are currently doing are quite common practice in this case.

Comment: 1) You need a staging table somewhere. You could use Spark Streaming or Nifi to watch a folder and convert immediately to Parquet for you, though. 2) Are csv files added to date directories in HDFS for Hive partitions? Or only added to a single path, and if so, how do you know which new files need processed?

Comment: As of now we are just doing the activity manually every day. Going forward  our plan is to extract the file from sftp folder, place this file in hdfs location (this is planned to implement via autosys.) .So once the file comes to my HDFS location i need to process it in to tables. We have date in the file name so its easy to identify the exact file name. @cricket_007

Comment: @leftjoin Yes, when i am doing 1) drop parquet table 2) insert into parquet select * from first table i.e. csv serde table it works fine.  But every time i can not drop it and create it again. Can you please how to proceed.

Comment: @Hari And why are you drop/create target table every time. This is not clear. Why not insert [overwrite] table [partition]?

Comment: Normally we are doing this one..every month dropping and creating again. Insert overwrite is also a best option. But every day doing insert overwrite is not feasible. we have vast amount of data and there are around 100 tables..

Comment: As mentioned, Apache NiFi can read from SFTP, and push to HDFS/Hive as well as do transformations along the way https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/97773/how-to-retrieve-files-from-a-sftp-server-using-nif.html